# products images are not show on frontend as well as backend in magento1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using csv file for uploading products.but it is not show product images for both sides frontend and backend

Comment: update your question with sample import file which you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Its seem's that your images are not in `Import` folder
Put all images into the `media/import` folder and then in your csv file.

"image","small_image","thumbnail"
"/6700ST_Beachlg.jpg","/6700ST_Beach.jpg","/6700ST_Beachsm.jpg"

Comment: sir,I am already created import folder and images in it.

Comment: Check the paths in CSV it should be like this `/image-name.jpg`, Also another thing check if image extension is capital or lower, e.g .JPG or .jpg so put image name with extension accordingly.

Comment: its not working all are set in correct place

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with permissions, make a test with 757

Answer (score 0):

Just a remark to above advices.
images have to be placed in media/import file before you import products with .csv file.
Not after!!!
Magento import tool looks for images in import file and then places them in right dir
Like this->
media/catalog/product/1/1/someimage.jpg